# UITableViewCell dynamic height with multiple dynamic elements

Tags: ios, height, uitableview

I have a tableViewCell with elements (c - means constraint):

- Label: fixed c.height (unimportant)
- Label1: multiline, word wrap, c.height >= 20
- Label2: multiline, word wrap, c.height >= 16
- ImageView: aspectFit, c.height >= 100. Outlet for height
- Label: fixed c.height (unimportant)

TableView have set estimatedH = 30 and rowH = Automatic

Compression/hugging priorities wasn't changed - default, bcs all elements have equal priority

in cellForRow I set Label1 and Label2 text (2 lines and 3 lines accordingly). Also I call SDWebImage method sd_setImage for imageView with completion. In completion I set imageView height, according to formula:

> newHeight = (cell.newsImageView.bounds.width / image.size.width) * image.size.height

But as result, my Labels shows maximum 2 lines of text and imageView has an incorrect height. After tableView reloading (pull-to-refresh) or for new dequed cells all Ok, but for visible - not good.

I've tried to prefetch images using SDWebImagePrefetcher and reload table in its completion, but this don't help

Any ideas how to fix this behaviour?

**Upd 05.04.17**

Here is log stack about constraint conflict. Maybe it can help to analyze issue.

```
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797a1ec0 V:[UILabel:0x7b06b990'22.03.2017 '(16)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797c7250 V:[UIImageView:0x797e6560(214.2)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797ca430 V:[UILabel:0x797c7900'\U0427\U0418\U0422\U0410\U0422\U0418 \U041d\U041e\U0412\U0418\U041d\U0423'(20)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797d7ac0 V:|-(16)-[UILabel:0x7b06b990'22.03.2017 ']   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b0810d0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797d2ac0 V:[UILabel:0x7b06b990'22.03.2017 ']-(0)-[UILabel:0x797c40a0'\U0406\U043d\U0444\U043e\U0440\U043c\U0430\U0446\U0456\U044f \U0434\U043b\U044f \U0430\U0431\U043e\U043d\U0435\U043d\U0442\U0456\U0432 ...']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797d2b80 V:[UILabel:0x797c40a0'\U0406\U043d\U0444\U043e\U0440\U043c\U0430\U0446\U0456\U044f \U0434\U043b\U044f \U0430\U0431\U043e\U043d\U0435\U043d\U0442\U0456\U0432 ...']-(0)-[UILabel:0x797c9090'\U0417 1 \U043a\U0432\U0456\U0442\U043d\U044f 2017 \U0440\U043e\U043a\U0443 \U043f\U0440\U043e\U0432...']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797d7c70 V:[UILabel:0x797c9090'\U0417 1 \U043a\U0432\U0456\U0442\U043d\U044f 2017 \U0440\U043e\U043a\U0443 \U043f\U0440\U043e\U0432...']-(10)-[UIImageView:0x797e6560]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797d7d00 V:[UIImageView:0x797e6560]-(10)-[UILabel:0x797c7900'\U0427\U0418\U0422\U0410\U0422\U0418 \U041d\U041e\U0412\U0418\U041d\U0423']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797d7d30 V:[UILabel:0x797c7900'\U0427\U0418\U0422\U0410\U0422\U0418 \U041d\U041e\U0412\U0418\U041d\U0423']-(10)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b0810d0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797d8160 V:[UIView:0x7b0810d0]-(5)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7b151eb0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797d8190 V:|-(5)-[UIView:0x7b0810d0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7b151eb0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x797dacb0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7b151eb0(274)]>"
```

)

Upd: [Sample project](https://github.com/OlesenkoViktor/TestDynamicCellHeight)

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the estimatedH = 30 but you have actually much more contents

20 + 16 + 100 = 136 which is much more than your estimation

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150
```

if you want to update specific cells after downloading your data then you can call the update table view

```
 self.tableview.beginUpdates()
 tableview.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with:.bottom)
 self.tableview.endUpdates()
```

reloadRows has enum for the options which you can access those with dot notation which I have selected .bottom but you can select from the enum which ever matches your need

Updated: [Sample Project](https://www.swiftyninja.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/TestDynamicCellHeight-master.zip)

Comment: estimatedHeight is some predefined value which will be overriden by constraints calculation. I set 30 for case, when I wouldn't have image, but only text values.
Also I couldn't use reloadRows or begin/endUpdates inside of cellForRow bcs it will lead for looping

P.S. just for be sure, I checked cases with different estimatedH: less, equal and greater values than real cell height - no difference

Comment: I think your problem is with ImageView's size inside your custom cell if you have. Or where ever your setting the image after ImageView.image = UIImage you have to call the sizeToFit() on the image view so image view knows it's size you can do this on your labels as well it will fix it. ImageView.sizeToFit()

Comment: `sizeToFit` doesn't help
I tried to add height constraint for both labels and set their height programmatically - all ok with them until image loading finished and image height was set

This reproducing only for inited cells. All ok with reused. I replaced set-height logic to `willDisplayCell` and call `cell.setNeedLayout` and `cell.layoutIfNeeded` at start, but this don't help.


Added constraints conflict log to question

Comment: It's difficult without the project or codes how you do them to give more suggestion it can be anything. Maybe your updating or calling tableview reload from a background not main queue.

Comment: from main. I will prepare sample proj and provide it later

Comment: Added Test Sample project to question description

Comment: I updated your project you can download it from my answer